Using Generating Functions To Count Things
At the theater, the movie X is currently showing. However, there are only $7$ tickets left in row $F$, $8$ tickets left in row $G$, and $9$ tickets left in row $H$.
A group of students enters the theater and wants to buy $6$ tickets with the requirement that there must be tickets in each of the three rows $F$, $G$, and $H$.
How many ways can the ticket seller sell tickets to the group of students?
I have done Direct Counting.
The answer to the counting problem is
$$C_{24}^6-[C_{15}^6+C_{17}^6+C_{16}^6-\left(C_7^6+C_8^6+C_9^6\right)]=109326.$$
I think the problem can use generating functions.
I am looking for such a way.

Does it matter to which student each ticket is distributed to? Or just the seats?

This is a math problem from my school, the solution is purely combinatorial. Here is the solution using generating functions. The problem of taking $n$ coins from $24$ people, with each person taking at most $1$ coin, can be represented by the generating function:
$$[(1+x)^7-1] \cdot[(1+x)^8-1]\cdot [(1+x)^9-1]$$
$$=(1+x)^{24}-[(1+x)^{17}+(1+x)^{16}+(1+x)^{15}]+(1+x)^9+(1+x)^8+(1+x)^7-1.$$
The coefficient containing $x^n$ will be
$$\binom{24}{n}-\left[\binom{17}{n}+\binom{16}{n}+\binom{15}{n}\right]+\binom{9}{n}+\binom{8}{n}+\binom{7}{n}.$$

Applying generating function is not much use here.
Still , using that might help in getting familiarity with that concept.
Let us make the Polynomial where the Co-efficients are the number of ways to select $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or more tickets out of $7$ seats :
It is this :
$(1+7X+21X^2+35X^3+35X^4+21X^5+7X^6+1X^7)$
Similarly , we can make the Polynomial where the Co-efficients are the number of ways to select $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or more tickets out of $8$ seats :
$(1+8X+28X^2+56X^3+70X^4+56X^5+28X^6+8X^7+1X^8)$
Like-wise ,  we can make the Polynomial where the Co-efficients are the number of ways to select $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or more tickets out of $8$ seats :
$(1+9X+36X^2+84X^3+126X^4+126X^5+84X^6+36X^7+9X^8+1X^9)$
When we multiply these , we will get the ways , which includes $0$ tickets in some rows.
We do not want $0$ tickets , hence we remove that term in the Polynomials & then multiply.
$(7X+21X^2+35X^3+35X^4+21X^5+7X^6+1X^7)(8X+28X^2+56X^3+70X^4+56X^5+28X^6+8X^7+1X^8)(9X+36X^2+84X^3+126X^4+126X^5+84X^6+36X^7+9X^8+1X^9)$
Pick the Co-efficent of $X^6$ to get the Count.
When I ask Wolfram :
EXPAND (7X+21X^2+35X^3+35X^4+21X^5+7X^6+1X^7)(8X+28X^2+56X^3+70X^4+56X^5+28X^6+8X^7+1X^8)(9X+36X^2+84X^3+126X^4+126X^5+84X^6+36X^7+9X^8+1X^9)  

It says :

We can see that the Co-efficent of $X^6$ is indeed $109326$
It is more work here.
We can get familiarity with the technique to use elsewhere.

In actual computation, you can ignore all the powers above 6. This is still small enough to do by hand. And I think you can multiply polynomials in O(n log n) with FFT?

Nice Point ignoring larger Powers , @qwr , though not sure what syntax I have to use with Wolfram. I am not much aware of Polynomial Multiplication with FFT , though I think what you say is right.

Idk the Mathematica syntax. Maybe you can work mod X^7 to not consider higher powers.

That sounds like a Workable Suggestion , @qwr , thanks !!
